# js jquery / if checkbox:checked - в textarea содержимое чекбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать что бы при активном чекбоксе (:checked) - по его классу/имени или другом способе его внутренний текст автоматически вносился в textarea. При отмене - текст удалялся (но только тот текст что мы добавляли с помощью чекбокса). Не важно как реализовано, текст чекбокса мы всегда знаем, и можем его задать через переменную, или использовать атрибуты, или его лейбл, это не принципиально.

Мы выделяем чекбокс 1, в textarea добавляеться текст "privetMir1".
Пример: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKxjaB

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="text1">privetMir1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text1" id="text1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <label for="text2">privetMir2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text2" id="text2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Comment</td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov спасибо за правки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getReg = str => new RegExp(str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));

[...document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]')].forEach(chbx => {
  chbx.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let txt = e.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      comment.value = (comment.value + ' ' + txt).trim();
    } else {
      comment.value = comment.value.replace(getReg(txt), '').trim();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <label for="text1">privetMir1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text1" id="text1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="text2">privetMir2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text2" id="text2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Comment</td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10">Some text</textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

На всякий случай, вариант с использованием jQuery:

```
const comment = $('#comment');
const getReg = str => new RegExp(str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"));

$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  let $that = $(this),
    txt = $that.prev().text();
  if ($that.is(':checked')) {
    comment.val($.trim(comment.val() + ' ' + txt));
  } else {
    comment.val($.trim(comment.val().replace(getReg(txt), '')));
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо Ваш вариант работает! Не могли бы уточнить, если я меняю местами лейбл и инпут, скрипт не работает, я не могу уследить в Вашем коде где именно идет обращение к лейблу впереди. Можете подсказать вариант с лейблом сзади? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKxjaB. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @IvanP, `$that.prev().text();` перед, `$that.next().text();` - после

Comment: ага, супер, все работает, но возник еще 1 косяк. У меня в одной части страницы есть еще один выбор чекбоксов  - с 2 опциями с другого скрипта( я этого не указывал), если выбрать один чекбокс - второй unchecked. И с этими элементами скрипт только добавляет их значения в textarea, но не удаляет, когда 1 элемент становиться unchecked.  На других чекбоксах (как в примере) работает как положено. Нужен полный скрипт привести с анчеком или можете как-то подкрутить "на глаз"?

Comment: или просто сделать проверку, если ничего не выбрано ( все unckecked ) - форма textarea состоящая из текста чекбоксов была пустая ИЛИ ( если можно) содержала только введенный вручную текст. П. С. спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @IvanP, я думаю, что более точный селектор для checkbox-ов решит проблему. Например, пишем не просто `$(':checkbox')`, а отталкиваясь от формы, в которой они расположены. У этой формы, как я вижу, есть атрибут `name="form1"`. Вот его можно взять за основу: `$('form[name="form1"]').find(':checkbox')`

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    const text = $(this).prev().text();
    const area = $('#comment');
    let val = area.val();
    if (this.checked)
      val += text;
    else
      val = val.replace(text, '');
    area.val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="text1">privetMir1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text1" id="text1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="text2">privetMir2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="text2" id="text2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Comment</td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```